# langchain.document_loaders PyPDFDirectoryLoader throws PdfReadError

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, langchain, py-langchain

I'm exploring loading a folder of 5 pdfs and am getting this error. Is there a way to skip this pdf or still parse it?

"PyPDFDirectoryLoader" PdfReadError: Invalid Elementary Object{tok!r} @{stream.tell()}: {stream.read(80).**repr**()}"

Code:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader, PyPDFDirectoryLoader

...

loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader(pdf_folder_path)
data = loader.load()
```

Stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PdfReadError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-1e2c570121f4> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # load your data
----> 2 data = loader.load()

...
...

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pypdf/_reader.py in get_object(self, indirect_reference)
   1399             if self.strict:
   1400                 assert generation == indirect_reference.generation
-> 1401             retval = read_object(self.stream, self)  # type: ignore
   1402 
   1403             # override encryption is used for the /Encrypt dictionary

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pypdf/generic/_data_structures.py in read_object(stream, pdf, forced_encoding)
   1296     else:
   1297         stream.seek(-20, 1)
-> 1298         raise PdfReadError(
   1299             f"Invalid Elementary Object starting with {tok!r} @{stream.tell()}: {stream.read(80).__repr__()}"
   1300         )

PdfReadError: Invalid Elementary Object starting with b'!' @25297125: b'\xd1h;\xa8p\xb4)\xdb\xa8\xa6yUgW\x98\xb2 7WU!\xa5\xd3\x9d\xd2\xa1Q\xf2J\xdb\xbfI\xaf\xd2\xe0\xa6\xae+\x8c\n\x92^`"\xccLDm\xbd\xe9{0@\x99a\xf1d\\\xa6qZb\x1c;%`l\x88\xcd\x1a\x0bw\xa806\x9b\xbc\x00\x16^'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you're trying to read a PDF that is broken.

Use

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

PdfReader("your.pdf")
```

to check which PDF is broken. Then remove it from your dataset.

If the PDF can be opened with a PDF reader, you can also post the PDF to the pypdf issue tracker: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues